# How to override ShinobiChart class in Swift

Tags: swift, shinobi

I use Shinobi 2.8.2 chart premium library, and I am trying to override `ShinobiChart` class, but I get 65 errors.

```
Apple Mach-O Linker Error
   Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
    "typeinfo for std::exception", referenced from:
       typeinfo for std::__1::bad_function_call in ShinobiCharts(ShinobiCharts)
    "typeinfo for std::__1::ios_base", referenced from:
       typeinfo for std::__1::basic_ios<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > in ShinobiCharts(ShinobiCharts)
    "vtable for __cxxabiv1::__class_type_info", referenced from:
       typeinfo for SChartGL::AnimationManager in ShinobiCharts(ShinobiCharts)
       typeinfo for SChartGL::ErrorHandler in ShinobiCharts(ShinobiCharts)
       typeinfo for SChartGL::VertexMath::convertSeries2DToGLVertex3DWithMultipleBaselines(float*,  SChartGL::GLVertex3D*, int, GLColour4f const*, GLColour4f const*, SChartGL::orientation, float)::$_0 in ShinobiCharts(ShinobiCharts)
       typeinfo for SChartGL::VertexMath::convertSeries2DToGLVertex3DWithBaseline(std::__1::vector<SChartGL::Point, std::__1::allocator<SChartGL::Point> >, SChartGL::GLVertex3DWithCurvature*, float, SChartGL::orientation, GLColour4f const&, GLColour4f const&)::$_1 in ShinobiCharts(ShinobiCharts)
       typeinfo for SChartGL::VertexMath::convertSeries2DToGLVertex3DWithInterpolatedGradientFill(float*, SChartGL::GLVertex3D*, int, GLColour4f const&, GLColour4f const&, float)::$_2 in ShinobiCharts(ShinobiCharts)
       typeinfo for std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > in ShinobiCharts(ShinobiCharts)
       typeinfo for SChartGL::RenderData in ShinobiCharts(ShinobiCharts)
...
```

What I did is :

```
import UIKit
import ShinobiCharts


class BIGraphChartView: ShinobiChart {

}
```

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry all for that.

For all other who will have same trouble : don't forget to include `libc++.tbd`